# how to resolve the cordova installation issue

Tags: ios, cordova

I am trying to create cordova using the terminal but I am getting following error.
So far I know this is the only user account which we had created and intact should 
be the root account

```
install -g cordova
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/anantmac
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova'
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/anantmac/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
Anants-MacBook-Air:~ anantmac$
```

Comment: try `sudo npm install -g cordova`

Comment: @Dawson. It was "sudo npm install -g cordova" and than I was supposed to enter the password. Thanks

Comment: glad to hear! I added this as an answer for others that find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes when installing node packages you need to use `sudo` so everything can write to the paths required, try this:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```